# Expected method to read dictionary element not found on object of type "class"

Tags: ios, objective-c, subscript

I'm trying to implement keyed subscripting for a custom class in Objective-C:

This is what I have in the header:

```
- (id)objectAtKeyedSubscript:(id <NSCopying>)key;
```

And this is what I have in the implementation:

```
- (id)objectAtKeyedSubscript:(id <NSCopying>)key
{
    id result = self.attributes[key];
    return result;  
}
```

I use it like so:

```
element[@"href"];
```

where before I did:

```
[element objectForKey:@"href"];
```

where objectForKey was being implemented like so:

```
- (NSString *) objectForKey:(NSString *) theKey
{
    return [[self attributes] objectForKey:theKey];
}
```

Something I'm missing? Doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name of the method is `objectForKeyedSubscript:`, not `objectAtKeyedSubscript:`.

Answer (score 1):

Despite a lot of appearances of the name "objectAtKeyedSubscript:" [out there on the web](http://www.google.com/search?q=objectAtKeyedSubscript%3a), the [correct method name is `objectForKeyedSubscript:`](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html#dictionary-style-subscripting)

Notice that this parallels the non-subscript method name `objectForKey:`, as `objectAtIndexedSubscript:` does `objectAtIndex:`